# Connecting domain and email hosting from one.com to Netlify

Tags: domains, dns, https, email, netlify

I am a beginner of webdevelopment and have successfully deployed my website at Netlify. I bought a domain with email hosting at one.com and now I want to redirect it to Netlify DNS to be provided with their TLS certificate, as the plan I bought from one.com doesn't have this. But the problem is that Netlify doesn't provide email but I am able to save it by copying the MX records at one, which I can't find anywhere. I successfully set up the domain email on gmail through IMAP, but don't know if it's encrypted. Is there any way to solve this, or should I just give up on the email hosting?

Answer (score 1):

Google does require encryption for IMAP and SMTP through their servers From [their help document](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-change-smtp-other-settings-in-your-email-client) (emphasis added):

> #### Incoming Mail (IMAP) Server
>
> - imap.gmail.com
> - **Requires SSL: Yes**
> - Port: 993
>
> #### Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server
>
> - smtp.gmail.com
> - **Requires SSL: Yes**
> - **Requires TLS: Yes (if available)**
> - Requires Authentication: Yes
> - Port for SSL: 465
> - Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587

So if you have mail set up with Google, I'd think you are good and you should stop there.  However if you want to find your `MX` records used at `one.com` you should be able to look them up from their nameservers.   I don't know what their nameservers actually are, but they are problably something like `ns1.one.com` and `ns2.one.com`.   The actual values should be in your account.   You can use `dig` on the command line to find the `MX` records:

```
dig @ns1.one.com MX mydomain.example
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems that POP3 is the method to set up domain email through gmail on Macbook? Is that as safe as IMAP?

Comment: Google also uses TLS for POP3.  Mac mail clients support IMAP and I recommend using it if possible.  It is designed to work with multiple folders and leave mail on the server.   POP is a holdover from when email was assumed to be one mailbox folder that got downloaded locally and deleted from the server.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. So, if I want to recieve domain emails through Gmail but still point the DNS servers to Netlify to host the website, I would need to change the MX records to  Gmail server at one.com?

Comment: Your MX records control which server receives the email for your domain.  It is a bit unclear to me who is hosting your DNS now.  If your NS records point to netlify, you need to set the MX records there. If your NS records point to one.com you need to set the MX records there.